# readHTMLTable doesnt always read all sheets from google docs spreadsheets

Tags: xml, r, google-docs

I am trying to import updated info from a google docs spreadsheet that is updated on an irregular time basis with R package XML. for some reason it reads sometimes only the first sheet and sometimes all the sheets (there are 25 in this document). an extra caveat is that there is hebrew in the spreadsheets and its not being encoded correctly - most of the time.

```
url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13XIAgbVk_c2Zxxa5xsR0EJFb6W9HMQpAjBImtFxZdxo/"

Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Hebrew")

readGoogleSheet <- function(url, na.string="", header=TRUE){
require(XML)
doc <- paste(readLines(url), collapse=" ")
htmlTable <- gsub("^.*?(<table.*</table).*$", "\\1>", doc)
ret <- readHTMLTable(htmlTable,
                    header=T,
                    stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                    as.data.frame=TRUE,
                   .Encoding="UTF-8")
```

Comment: you might be interested in a package in development for working with google spreadsheets https://github.com/jennybc/gspreadr - which might be easier

Answer (score 2):

The package mentioned in the comments above is ready for use now and has been renamed `googlesheets`:

https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets

This snippet will install the package, copy a Sheet to your Google Drive, register it for access, and import data from one tab or worksheet into a local data.frame:

```
devtools::install_github("jennybc/googlesheets")
gap_key <- "1HT5B8SgkKqHdqHJmn5xiuaC04Ngb7dG9Tv94004vezA"
copy_ss(key = gap_key, to = "Gapminder")
gap <- register_ss("Gapminder")
oceania <- get_via_csv(gap, ws = "Oceania")
oceania
```